# search an array of objects for value

Tags: angular

I have an array of object that looks like this

```
class ValueError {
  value: string;
  error?: string;

  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
    this.error = null;
  }
}

export class Record {
  productId: ValueError;
  dpt: ValueError;
  storeNumber: ValueError;
  email: ValueError;
}
```

I want to search this array for product id (value) and storeNumber (value). this is what i've tried so far. i don't know how to search for the value

```
searchBy = '123';
filter() {
   const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.allRecords));
   Object.keys.forEach(key => {
   result[key] = result[key].filter(r=> (r.productId.value) && (this.searchBy.includes(r.productId.value)))
})
}
```

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.allRecords)) why? I assume allRecords is an array of Record? then just do: allRecords.filter(r => r.productId?.value === searchBy)

Comment: find my answer below.

Comment: the below solution didn't work for you?

Comment: i saw it just now, it is the solution I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below method will return you filtered array. because you seem to have a array of object. so a normal filter method can be used to return a new array with filtered value.

```
public filter() {
  return result.filter((r) => (r.productId.value) && (this.searchBy.includes(r.productId.value)));
}
```